# Python 3.6.5 and cx_freeze :

Tags: cx-freeze

I got this message when trying to execute python executable program, build with `cxfreeze`, but when I execute the python script `.py`, there is no problems

```
D:\TEST2000>Get-List-FoldersID-and-Titles.exe Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python-365\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py", line 14, in run module.run() File "C:\Python-365\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run exec(code, m.dict) File "D:\TEST2000\Get-List-FoldersID-and-Titles.py", line 5, in import requests File "C:\Python-365\lib\site-packages\requests__init__.py", line 98, in from . import packages File "C:\Python-365\lib\site-packages\requests\packages.py", line 7, in locals()[package] = import(package) File "C:\Python-365\lib\site-packages\idna__init__.py", line 2, in from .core import * File "C:\Python-365\lib\site-packages\idna\core.py", line 1, in from . import idnadata ImportError: cannot import name 'idnadata'
```

How do I resolve the `ImportError` that I am getting?

Comment: Is `idnadata` a custom module?

Answer (score 0):

`idnadata` is a module from the `idna` package. When you build the executable with cx_Freeze, use the [`packages`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe) option to include the `idna` package.

In your setup.py

```
setup(
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "packages": ["idna"],
            },
        },
    )
```